# Upload images into S3 bucket with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I able to upload to the bucket like this

`s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new`

`s3.bucket(bucket).object(fileName).upload_file(path)`

but I want to upload the file into a folder inside the bucket?

Comment: your `path` contains folders. Specify the path of the folder in which you want to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that like this

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

s3.bucket(bucket).object(folder_name/fileName).upload_file(path)
```

When you upload to s3 with a `/` in the name it assumes its a directory if that directory does not exist AWS will just create it.